# why sklearn MinMaxScaler normalizing sparse matrix will output only -1 and 1 value

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to use `MinMaxScaler` to normalize a sparse matrix, and I set the range to [-1, 1], but the result only gives me -1 and 1 int values. I don't know what I should change the setting of the scaler.

**My output is like this :**

```
list_1:  [[11.41822609 -1.88521764  3.23520926]
 [10.21012252 -1.05147544  6.925866  ]]

scaled:  [[ 1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.]] 

transfer:  [[11.41822609 -1.88521764  3.23520926]
 [10.21012252 -1.05147544  6.925866  ]]
```

**my code :**

```
file = h5py.File('HDF5s\\xy_train&std_data.hdf5', 'r')
dataset = numpy.array(file['s1']['V1']['cnn1']['n_train'])
file.close()

list_1 = numpy.array(dataset[:2, :3], dtype='float64')

scaler_1 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
s_list_1 = scaler_1.fit_transform(list_1)

print('list_1: ', list_1, '\n')
print('scaled: ', s_list_1, '\n')
print('transfer: ', scaler_1.inverse_transform(s_list_1), '\n')
```

Comment: You only have two values per column. `MinMaxScaler` fits and transforms each column not each row.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Scikit-learn: How to normalize row values horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759585/scikit-learn-how-to-normalize-row-values-horizontally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've fit your `MinMaxScaler()` to a numpy array with shape `(2,3)`. `MinMaxScaler()` will scale each feature (i.e. each column) separately. In the case of the array you supplied, there are only 2 values (i.e rows) for each feature, so the higher value becomes the upper bound for that feature (1), and the lower value becomes the lower bound (-1), hence all values are either -1 or 1.

If you fit the MinMaxScaler to a larger sample (i.e. more rows) then you will see the scaled values are no longer just -1 and 1.